# Hyperledger: Certificate Issue while bootstrapping the network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Receiving an error while bootstrapping the network -
panic: Failed validating bootstrap block: initializing channelconfig failed: could not create channel Consortiums sub-group config: setting up the MSP manager failed: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority. This error is specific to the TLS CA root certificate. (crypto/ca-cert of TLSCA). Am I anything missing here? Followed Fabric CA Operations guide for implementing the network on multihost environment.

**Docker log-**

```
 2020-07-07 01:48:45.066 UTC [localconfig] completeInitialization -> WARN 001 General.GenesisFile should be replaced by General.BootstrapFile
2020-07-07 01:48:45.066 UTC [localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 002 Kafka.Version unset, setting to 0.10.2.0
2020-07-07 01:48:45.066 UTC [orderer.common.server] prettyPrintStruct -> INFO 003 Orderer config values:
    General.ListenAddress = "0.0.0.0"
    General.ListenPort = 7050
    General.TLS.Enabled = true
    General.TLS.PrivateKey = "/etc/hyperledger/ordererorg/ord1/tls-msp/keystore/key.pem"
    General.TLS.Certificate = "/etc/hyperledger/ordererorg/ord1/tls-msp/signcerts/cert.pem"
    General.TLS.RootCAs = [/etc/hyperledger/ordererorg/ord1/tls-msp/tlscacerts/tls-ca-tls-cvs-org-7054.pem]
    General.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
    General.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
    General.Cluster.ListenAddress = ""
    General.Cluster.ListenPort = 0
    General.Cluster.ServerCertificate = ""
    General.Cluster.ServerPrivateKey = ""
    General.Cluster.ClientCertificate = "/etc/hyperledger/ordererorg/ord1/tls-msp/signcerts/cert.pem"
    General.Cluster.ClientPrivateKey = "/etc/hyperledger/ordererorg/ord1/tls-msp/keystore/key.pem"
    General.Cluster.RootCAs = [/etc/hyperledger/ordererorg/ord1/tls-msp/tlscacerts/tls-ca-tls-cvs-org-7054.pem]
    General.Cluster.DialTimeout = 5s
    General.Cluster.RPCTimeout = 7s
    General.Cluster.ReplicationBufferSize = 20971520
    General.Cluster.ReplicationPullTimeout = 5s
    General.Cluster.ReplicationRetryTimeout = 5s
    General.Cluster.ReplicationBackgroundRefreshInterval = 5m0s
    General.Cluster.ReplicationMaxRetries = 12
    General.Cluster.SendBufferSize = 10
    General.Cluster.CertExpirationWarningThreshold = 168h0m0s
    General.Cluster.TLSHandshakeTimeShift = 0s
    General.Keepalive.ServerMinInterval = 1m0s
    General.Keepalive.ServerInterval = 2h0m0s
    General.Keepalive.ServerTimeout = 20s
    General.ConnectionTimeout = 0s
    General.GenesisMethod = "file"
    General.GenesisFile = "/etc/hyperledger/ordererorg/ord1/genesis.block"
    General.BootstrapMethod = "file"
    General.BootstrapFile = "/etc/hyperledger/ordererorg/ord1/genesis.block"
    General.Profile.Enabled = false
    General.Profile.Address = "0.0.0.0:6060"
    General.LocalMSPDir = "/etc/hyperledger/ordererorg/ord1/msp"
    General.LocalMSPID = "OrdererMSP"
    General.BCCSP.ProviderName = "SW"
    General.BCCSP.SwOpts.SecLevel = 256
    General.BCCSP.SwOpts.HashFamily = "SHA2"
    General.BCCSP.SwOpts.Ephemeral = true
    General.BCCSP.SwOpts.FileKeystore.KeyStorePath = ""
    General.BCCSP.SwOpts.DummyKeystore =
    General.BCCSP.SwOpts.InmemKeystore =
    General.Authentication.TimeWindow = 15m0s
    General.Authentication.NoExpirationChecks = false
    FileLedger.Location = "/var/hyperledger/production/orderer"
    FileLedger.Prefix = "hyperledger-fabric-ordererledger"
    Kafka.Retry.ShortInterval = 5s
    Kafka.Retry.ShortTotal = 10m0s
    Kafka.Retry.LongInterval = 5m0s
    Kafka.Retry.LongTotal = 12h0m0s
    Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.DialTimeout = 10s
    Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.ReadTimeout = 10s
    Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.WriteTimeout = 10s
    Kafka.Retry.Metadata.RetryMax = 3
    Kafka.Retry.Metadata.RetryBackoff = 250ms
    Kafka.Retry.Producer.RetryMax = 3
    Kafka.Retry.Producer.RetryBackoff = 100ms
    Kafka.Retry.Consumer.RetryBackoff = 2s
    Kafka.Verbose = true
    Kafka.Version = 0.10.2.0
    Kafka.TLS.Enabled = false
    Kafka.TLS.PrivateKey = ""
    Kafka.TLS.Certificate = ""
    Kafka.TLS.RootCAs = []
    Kafka.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
    Kafka.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
    Kafka.SASLPlain.Enabled = false
    Kafka.SASLPlain.User = ""
    Kafka.SASLPlain.Password = ""
    Kafka.Topic.ReplicationFactor = 1
    Debug.BroadcastTraceDir = "data/logs"
    Debug.DeliverTraceDir = ""
    Consensus = map[SnapDir:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/etcdraft/snapshot WALDir:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/etcdraft/wal]
    Operations.ListenAddress = "127.0.0.1:8443"
    Operations.TLS.Enabled = false
    Operations.TLS.PrivateKey = ""
    Operations.TLS.Certificate = ""
    Operations.TLS.RootCAs = []
    Operations.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
    Operations.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
    Metrics.Provider = "disabled"
    Metrics.Statsd.Network = "udp"
    Metrics.Statsd.Address = "127.0.0.1:8125"
    Metrics.Statsd.WriteInterval = 30s
    Metrics.Statsd.Prefix = ""
2020-07-07 01:48:45.078 UTC [orderer.common.server] initializeServerConfig -> INFO 004 Starting orderer with TLS enabled
2020-07-07 01:48:45.088 UTC [fsblkstorage] NewProvider -> INFO 005 Creating new file ledger directory at /var/hyperledger/production/orderer/chains
2020-07-07 01:48:45.092 UTC [orderer.common.server] Main -> PANI 006 Failed validating bootstrap block: initializing channelconfig failed: could not create channel Consortiums sub-group config: setting up the MSP manager failed: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
panic: Failed validating bootstrap block: initializing channelconfig failed: could not create channel Consortiums sub-group config: setting up the MSP manager failed: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore.(*CheckedEntry).Write(0xc0001c8580, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore/entry.go:230 +0x545
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).log(0xc0001ae310, 0x1191704, 0x100c164, 0x25, 0xc00033f910, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:234 +0x100
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).Panicf(...)
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:159
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging.(*FabricLogger).Panicf(...)
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging/zap.go:74
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.Main()
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:130 +0x1354
main.main()
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/cmd/orderer/main.go:15 +0x20
```

**configtx.yaml -**

```
---
Organizations:
    - &OrdererMSP
        Name: OrdererMSP
        ID: OrdererMSP
        MSPDir: /home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/cvs/OrgMSP/orderer.cvs.org/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"
        OrdererEndpoints:
            - ord1.ordererorg.cvs.org:7050
            - ord2.ordererorg.cvs.org:7050
            - ord3.ordererorg.cvs.org:7050
    - &TestOrg1MSP
        Name: TestOrg1MSP
        ID: TestOrg1MSP
        MSPDir: /home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/cvs/OrgMSP/TestOrg1.cvs.org/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('TestOrg1MSP.admin', 'TestOrg1MSP.peer', 'TestOrg1MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('TestOrg1MSP.admin', 'TestOrg1MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('TestOrg1MSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('TestOrg1MSP.peer')"
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer1.TestOrg1.cvs.org
              Port: 7051
    - &TestOrg2MSP
        Name: TestOrg2MSP
        ID: TestOrg2MSP
        MSPDir: /home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/cvs/OrgMSP/TestOrg2.cvs.org/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('TestOrg2MSP.admin', 'TestOrg2MSP.peer', 'TestOrg2MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('TestOrg2MSP.admin', 'TestOrg2MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('TestOrg2MSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('TestOrg2MSP.peer')"
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer1.TestOrg2.cvs.org
              Port: 7051
    - &TestOrg3MSP
        Name: TestOrg3MSP
        ID: TestOrg3MSP
        MSPDir: /home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/cvs/OrgMSP/TestOrg3.cvs.org/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('TestOrg3MSP.admin', 'TestOrg3MSP.peer', 'TestOrg3MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('TestOrg3MSP.admin', 'TestOrg3MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('TestOrg3MSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('TestOrg3MSP.peer')"
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer1.TestOrg3.cvs.org
              Port: 7051
Capabilities:
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        V2_0: true
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        V2_0: true
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        V2_0: true
Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    Organizations:
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        LifecycleEndorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
        Endorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
    OrdererType: etcdraft
    EtcdRaft:
        Consenters:
        - Host: ord1.ordererorg.cvs.org
          Port: 7050
          ClientTLSCert: /home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/cvs/OrgMSP/ord1.ordererorg.cvs.org/cert.pem
          ServerTLSCert: /home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/cvs/OrgMSP/ord1.ordererorg.cvs.org/cert.pem
        - Host: ord2.ordererorg.cvs.org
          Port: 7050
          ClientTLSCert: /home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/cvs/OrgMSP/ord2.ordererorg.cvs.org/cert.pem
          ServerTLSCert: /home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/cvs/OrgMSP/ord2.ordererorg.cvs.org/cert.pem
        - Host: ord3.ordererorg.cvs.org
          Port: 7050
          ClientTLSCert: /home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/cvs/OrgMSP/ord3.ordererorg.cvs.org/cert.pem
          ServerTLSCert: /home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/cvs/OrgMSP/ord3.ordererorg.cvs.org/cert.pem
    BatchTimeout: 2s
    BatchSize:
        MaxMessageCount: 10
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB
    Organizations:
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities
Profiles:
    ThreeOrgsChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *TestOrg1MSP
                - *TestOrg2MSP
                - *TestOrg3MSP
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
    SampleMultiNodeEtcdRaft:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ChannelCapabilities
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            OrdererType: etcdraft
            Addresses:
                - ord1.ordererorg.cvs.org:7050
                - ord2.ordererorg.cvs.org:7050
                - ord3.ordererorg.cvs.org:7050
            Organizations:
            - *OrdererMSP
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
            - <<: *OrdererMSP
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                - *TestOrg1MSP
                - *TestOrg2MSP
                - *TestOrg3MSP
                     
    channel1:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *TestOrg1MSP
                - *TestOrg2MSP
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
                
    channel2:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *TestOrg2MSP
                - *TestOrg3MSP
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say much without looking at your code. But it looks like you have either invalid or expired certificates(crypto materials).
You need to make sure that you are using same crypto materials for Generating Genesis Block, Creating Channel, and for the Orderer. Try regenerating the crypto materials and see if it works.

Comment: I entirely reran the installation steps to eliminate a similar issue - panic index of range, that occurred previously. I have set this up on 5 hosts, and rerunning everything again becomes is becoming costlier. There wasn't any error thrown while setting up the peers or OrgCA, even while creating TLS enrollment profiles from TLSCA which is hosted on a separate  host.  Created the genesis and channels boot strap / genesis files without any issues.. but only while creating the orderer with genesis block reference the error is thrown.

Comment: Can you share the content of your configtx.yaml and docker logs for orderer?